# how to provide synchronization between two processes using unnamed semaphores?

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

Can anyone explain "how to provide synchronization between two processes using unnamed semaphores?". while using semaphores what are the function calls needed and how the semaphores shares the shared memory region. what is the use of mmap() function call in synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

From the `sem_init` manual page:

```
   If pshared is non-zero, then the semaphore is shared between processes,
   and should be located in a region of shared  memory  (see  shm_open(3),
   mmap(2),  and  shmget(2)).   (Since a child created by fork(2) inherits
   its parent's memory mappings, it can also access the  semaphore.)   Any
   process  that  can  access  the shared memory region can operate on the
   semaphore using sem_post(3), sem_wait(3), etc.
```

Thus, you should create and attach shared memory using `shm_open`+`mmap` or `shmget`+`shmat`. Then you create the unnamed semaphore at the address by using `sem_init`. A child created by using the `fork()` system call inherits the memory mappings of the parent, so you can access the unnamed semaphore also in child processes.